# Do we have name for these images

Tags: graphic-design, graphics

I need to search these kind of images on google. But I don't know with what name shall I search for these images.

**Do we have name for these kind of images**
**not to confuse with gif images*

[image]

[image]

Comment: They're really just simplified icon-style illustrations. terms I'd consider for searching: flat, icons, pictograms, minimal

Comment: Usually when I search for these types of images, I add the search terms icon, symbol, diagram or image (whichever returns the best search results).

Comment: Graphic Design Junction calls it ["Flat Design"](http://graphicdesignjunction.com/2013/04/flat-devices-with-free-psd-mockups/). Have a look at [FltDsgn](http://fltdsgn.com/), [FlatUI](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/), [Flat Web Elements for UI Design](http://graphicdesignjunction.com/2013/04/flat-icons-and-web-elements-for-ui-design/) and [TNW](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2013/03/04/flat-ui-a-delightful-alternative-to-bootstraps-default-look-sans-gradients-and-drop-shadows/). Try [Googling 'Flat UI Design'](https://www.google.com/search?q=flat+ui+design) for more.